# how to write spark custom data source based on FileFormat

Tags: apache-spark, datasource

i saw the spark avro datasource is implemented based on FileFormat interface.
Is there any documentation about how to write spark custom datasource based on FileFormat? Up to now i can't find any(except the source code from spark avro).

Thank you!

Answer (score 6):

Here is an example of a simple file-based spark datasource: https://hackernoon.com/extending-our-spark-sql-query-engine-5f4a088de986

Here's a couple examples that implement the Data Sources API, as well:
* https://github.com/databricks/spark-csv
* https://github.com/databricks/spark-avro